# How to access variables declared in a playbook file inside a custom Ansible plugin?

Tags: ansible

I am going through the official Ansible documentation regarding [developing custom plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html). I am unable to find a way to access the variables declared in a playbook YML file from within the custom plugin (action). Is there a way to accomplish this task? I'd love to view a wiki page for the same (if it exists). TIA

For example:

1.) The playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: "Set facts"
    set_facts:
      gate_enabled: "True"
```

2.) The plugin:

```
class ActionModule(ActionBase):
  def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
    #access the variable gate_enabled here
```

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly. Please let me know if anything else is required. I'm very new to Ansible plugin development so I may miss something. I am developing an Action plugin.

Comment: See this as an example https://github.com/technekey/ansible-user-prompt . Not putting as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to access the playbook variables inside the action plugin using `ActionBase` class' `run` method's task_vars property. It is a *dictionary* type and one can use the `get` method to access a particular variable. Hope it helps others as well.

EDIT: Added code sample

```
class ActionModule(ActionBase):
  def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
    #access the variable gate_enabled here
    task_vars.get("gate_enabled")
```

Comment: Regarding "_Hope it helps others as well_" , it might if you show others how you've "_managed to access the playbook variables inside the action plugin using ActionBase class' run method's task_vars property. It is a dictionary type and one can use the get method to access a particular variable_".